# Actually what is the init parameter in servlet?

Tags: servlets

Friends tell me what is the core meaning of init parameter in case of a servlet.
I know that how to initialize it in a web.xml but I don't know what is the actual purpose of it why it is required? Please tell me with a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29) says: "A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's no need to call super.init(config)."

The init method's main purpose is to allow customization while you are initializing the servlet.

The simplest implementation is when you don't want to do any customization according to your application you can always call super.init method.

To understand meaning of what different init params can be there and how init method is useful:
Imagine a system Of BookManagement system, here for adding books and removing books from db you will be needing Database connection over which you can access the data. Now as Servlet's init method is called for the first request and database connection also needs be created only once(or n number of time if doing connection pooling) then initializing the database connection is something that you should do in init method.

A code snippet from [Softlab example](https://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/java/tutorial/servlets/lifecycle/init.html) , let's assume that getInitParameter method reads the databaseUrl and other properties from web.xml

```
public class DBServlet ... {

        Connection connection = null;

        public void init() throws ServletException {

            // Open a database connection to prepare for requests
            try {
                databaseUrl = getInitParameter("databaseUrl");
                ... // get user and password parameters the same way
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl,
                                                         user, password);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new UnavailableException (this,
            "Could not open a connection to the database");
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

One more example of counting the number of time servlet was accessed: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_03.htm

So in Summary: To do customization like read the initial values of variable or to initialize resources(like db connection) you can use init method.

Comment: Thanks, I got whatever I was wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the source code of init methods :

```
public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException
{
    this.config = config;
    int();
}

public void init() throws ServletException;
```

It is recommended to override to init() method, not init(ServletConfig).

When overriding init(ServletConfig), the first thing that must be done is to call:

super.init(config);
If you do this then calling directly to getServletContext() in your method will no longer result in an NPE.